# How can i make fully decentralized token pegged to BUSD or USDT?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, bsc, stablecoins

I am making an ecosystem, where i want to give rewards in my own stablecoin. How is it possible for me to make it fully decentralized, with minting and burning to maintain a fixed price to $1 when people buy and sell on for example pancakeswap?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just to give a short answer: it's very difficult to accomplish reliably.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are aiming to create an algorithmic stablecoin. I base this off of the fact that you want it to be "decentralized" and the "buying and selling" you mentioned.

This is basically what UST did. We all know how that turned out...

But here is the just of it:

1. Build a token, call it token A for this example.
2. Then build another token, call it token B. This is your stable token.
3. Then add liquidity to token B and token A. ex. B/ETH and A/ETH.
4. Then write an algorithm where token B is always equal to $1 based on firstly oracle data that you can fetch via chainlink related to the paired currency's pirce (in this case ETH). Then every time the token B depegs from $1 due to its price it gets from its DEX pair, either buy or sell token A/B to give or take liquidity to token B's pool.